# Debug Not Appearing in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I have set up debugging in my PHP code by starting the file:-

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

However it never displays any errors. At the moment I am mainly querying or updating database tables. Even if create an issue with working PHP, such as either missing out a bracket or semi-colon, or misspelling a column name the screen is blank with no errors. This makes debugging a slow process if you put in a chunk of code!

Comment: PHP won't display you any SQL errors. You have to check for SQL errors with the `mysqli_*` functions

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Seeing your code will help

Comment: pls show the code where you expect the error

Comment: Besides SQL errors I was also referring to syntactical errors such as a missing  semi-colon or incorrect bracketing.

Comment: @Jean-Michel Missing semi-colons isn't MySQL, that's where PHP would take that as a parse error and is where error reporting would kick in ;-)

Answer (score 0):

PHP's [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) does not report errors for MySQL, MySQL has its own error checking method.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- Consult my footnotes about this.

I.e.:

```
INSERT INTO table (column 1) VALUES ($string)
```

will throw two errors only if `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` is added to `mysqli_query()`.

Notice the space between `column` and `1` and not quoting the `$string` variable?

```
INSERT INTO table (`column 1`) VALUES ('$string')
```

while using ticks around the column name and quotes around the string value.

**Sidenote:**

Actually, it should technically be three errors, since technically speaking, `table` is a MySQL reserved word as is `column`.

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Therefore, that too needs to be wrapped in ticks.

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`column 1`) VALUES ('$string')
```

---

Same thing for a [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

```
SELECT column name with spaces-and-hyphens FROM table name WHERE column = string
```

which should read as:

```
SELECT `column name with spaces-and-hyphens` FROM `table name` WHERE `column` = 'string'
```

---

Now to purposely cause an error:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT `column name with spaces-and-hyphens` 
                  FROM `table name` WHERE `column` = 'string'";
```

will also throw an error because of the missing bracket.

or a missing quote:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT `column name with spaces-and-hyphens` 
         FROM `table name` WHERE `column` = 'string');
```

or a missing tick:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT `column name with spaces-and-hyphens 
         FROM `table name` WHERE `column` = 'string'");
```

---

Pulled from comments:

> *"Besides SQL errors I was also referring to syntactical errors such as a missing semi-colon or incorrect bracketing."*

**A:** Missing semi-colons isn't MySQL, that's where PHP would take that as a parse error and is where PHP's [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) would kick in.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// rest of your code
```

---

**Footnotes:** The `on` method is used inside `php.ini`

- `display_errors = on` rather than in `ini_set()`.

---

For more information on Identifier Qualifiers, visit:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

Comment: I did not post any code when requested as I have only just seen comment as I did not watch screen waiting for an answer!

Comment: @Jean-Michel No problemo. Well, I hope this helps.

Comment: @Jean-Michel Have I answered the question, or should I just delete it? I've made a few edits since you first saw it.

Comment: I have found typos such as parse errors are reported if I select Geany->Build->Execute but not if I use the browser which is how I would like to run it as the Geany terminal does not format correctly.

Comment: @Jean-Michel I'm not familiar with Geany.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding only the posted code, the correct way to enable the errors display is:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

The string `On` is evaluated to `0`. There is no wonder that it doesn't show any error.

The code above enables the display of runtime errors. The syntax errors are compilation errors; that means the code has no chance to run. In order to enable the display of compilation errors you have to edit `php.ini`.

On the production server is recommended to **not** display any errors in the page. Instead, log the runtime errors (see the [`log_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) ini configuration) and make sure there are no compilation errors by using a separate machine for development (and enable errors display on that machine).